# build mp4 file from mdat

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, mp4, mkv

I have mdat content that I parsed from mkv cluster/blocks it is basically the mdat section of the mp4 file contained in the mkv.

I would like to build a playable mp4 or ts file or any playable format from that mdat.

I already have all the required metadata parsed from the mkv file.

I already looked at ffmpeg and videojs/mux.js lib without success.

I'm building this using javascript in browser, the goal is to parse mkv, extract part of the content and play it in browser.

if I can convert a specific cluster from the mkv to a mp4 file that will be good too.

does anyone have an idea how I can proceed.
Thank you.